# Pass task output to Version property for Microsoft.NET.Sdk

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, dotnet-cli, dotnet-sdk

I'm trying to write up a `Directory.Build.*` file for my SDK-style `csproj` files. It should inject a common product version (from `VERSION.txt`) and add the git hash to it.

I only have rudimentary knowledge about MSBuild, I know how to look up the properties that the SDK uses and that properties are set in the evaluation phase first. I also found property functions and target definitions in the docs.

For this working example the `csproj` file contains only:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The following `Directory.Build.props` with only evaluation phase stuff works when doing `dotnet build /p:VcsDesc=123`:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove("VERSION.txt"))))+vcs$(VcsDesc)</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

For retrieving the `VcsDesc` automatically I tried defining a target

```xml
<Target Name="Foo" Outputs="VcsDesc">
  <Exec Command="git describe --always --tags --dirty" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="VcsDesc" />
  </Exec>
  <Message Importance="High" Text="VCS Descriptor = $(VcsDesc)" />
</Target>
```

which gets executed when I define it as `InitialTargets="Foo"` on the `Directory.Build.props` or when I add `DependsOnTargets="BeforeBuild"`. I know it gets executed because I see the message with the correct output from `git`. The property does not get picked by the SDK though (I see it missing from the generated NuGet spec).

I tried

- using `Directory.Build.targets` instead of `Directory.Build.props`
- setting the `Version` inside the `Foo` target which ends up with the default 1.0.0 version
- removing `Outputs` from the target
- `DependsOnTargets="Build"` instead of `BeforeBuild`

I think I am executing my target too early but I don't know where to find the right target to put in `DependsOnTargets`.

Any pointers are welcome.